# Solve linear system of equations in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

My textbook says that you can't do this using simple Gaussian elimination with a composite modulus because numbers don't necessarily have inverses, so they recommend the following steps:

- Get a prime factorization: $m = \prod\limits_i q_i^{e_i}$
- Solve the system of equations for each $\mathbb{Z}/q_i\mathbb{Z}$. Since $q_i$ is prime, all non-zero integers have inverses in $\mathbb{Z}/q_i\mathbb{Z}$ and straight forward Gaussian elimination works.
- "lift" each solution from $\mathbb{Z}/q_i\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/q_i^{e_i}\mathbb{Z}$
- combine all $\mathbb{Z}/q_i^{e_i}\mathbb{Z}$ solutions with the chinese remainder theorem to get the final solution in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Can someone explain the "lifting" step. How does that work?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Hensel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma)? Because that is precisely what the lifting step is.